# resolve promise after setTimeout inside promise

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, settimeout

I would like to resolve my promise after my setTimeout will be finished. I have a few functions like *step* The main idea is to get step results sequentially. P.S. we can't mutate setTimeout.

```
function step (done) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      setTimeout(done, 5100, 'hello world')
      resolve()
    } catch (error) {
      reject()
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: "P.S. we can't mutate setTimeout.", then, what can we modify?

Comment: @ikhvjs yea:( Do you have some idea how to solve it?

Comment: @АлександрАлександр, you didn't answer Kaiido's first comment. `what can we modify`?

Comment: @ikhvjs we have access to done callback, we can modify it if it helps

Comment: Why can you add `resolve` in the step function but not in an extra `setTimeout`callback? The logic won't change, its just written differently

Comment: Sorry for confusing guys. look... job (step) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
              step(arg => {
                resolve()
              })
            }.... I just have access to step and done callbacks, I have not opportunity to mutate setTimeout

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling this function `step` (or the `job` method from your last comment)? If you really want to use promises, you shouldn't need to pass a callback argument at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't mutate the `setTimeout` remove it. Instead of putting the `setTimeout` in the step function create a new `delay` function that returns a promise. You can then use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) to walk through the steps after certain delays.

```js
function delay(time = 1000) {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => res(), time); 
  });
}

function step(fn, n) {
  fn(`hello world ${n}`);
}

const fn = (str) => console.log(str);

async function main() {
  step(fn, 1);
  await delay(5000);
  step(fn, 2);
  await delay(3000);
  step(fn, 3);
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the `done` function, you can do like below.

```js
function step(done) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        immutableFunc(done(resolve, reject));
    });
}

function immutableFunc(done) {
    setTimeout(done, 1000, "hello world");
}

function done(resolve, reject) {
    return arg => {
        try {
            console.log(arg);
            resolve();
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    };
}

async function test() {
    try {
        await step(done);
        await step(done);
        await step(done);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

test();
```

Comment: No need to `try`/`catch` in (the synchronous parts of) the promise executor